# Python nested if statements failing to output value after input()

Tags: python, if-statement

I am making a logic gate program and have this code:

```
gate = input("Enter gate:\t")
in1 = input("\nEnter first input:\t")
in2 = input("\nEnter second input:\t")

if gate  == "OR":
  if in1 == 1:
    print("\nResult:\t1")

if gate  == "OR":
  if in1 == 1:
    print("\nResult:\t1")
  elif in2 == 1:
    print("\nResult:\t1")
  else:
    print("\nResult:\t0")

elif gate == "AND":
  if in1 == 1 and in2 == 1:
    print("\nResult:\t1")
  else:
    print("\nResult:\t0")

elif gate == "NAND":
  if in1 == 1 and in2 == 1:
    print("\nResult:\t0")
  else:
    print("\nResult:\t1")

elif gate == "XOR":
  if in1 != in2:
    print("\nResult:\t1")
  else:
    print("\nResult:\t0")

elif gate == "NOT":
  if in1 == 0:
    print("\nResult:\t1")
  else:
    print("\nResult:\t0")

elif gate == "NOR":
  if in1 == 0 and in2 == 0:
    print("\nResult:\t1")
  elif in1 == 0 and in2 == 1:
    print("\nResult:\t0")
  elif in1 == in2:
    print("\nResult:\t1")
  else:
    print("\nResult:\t0")

else:
  print("\nEnter a valid logic gate")
```

But it never returns anything.

I have also translated this into java and it also does not seem to be working

As an aside, on line 10, I get this error:
`[mccabe] Cyclomatic complexity too high: 16 (threshold 15)`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `input` returns string, cast it to int `in1 = int(input("\nEnter first input:\t"))`.

Comment: You assume that numbers entered through `input` will be numbers, rather than strings looking like numbers.

Answer (score 2):

`input()` returns a string value, so `in1` and `in2` are strings, but your `if` statements are looking for ints. You need to change your 2. and 3. Line to :

```
gate = input("Enter gate:\t")
in1 = int(input("\nEnter first input:\t"))
in2 = int(input("\nEnter second input:\t"))
```